# SiS 900 Fast Ethernet Adapter needs driver, But where?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, upgrade

I just recently got an compaq presario which had windows xp installed on it. I decided to put a bigger hard drive on it and upgrade it to windows 7.

When i did this, it did not recognize my sound card or my Ethernet adapter. Eventually I fixed my sound card by installing a more updated driver.

I know for a fact that I need to install a driver for my network card but I can‘t seem to find it online for windows 7. It is all either for windows xp or it is the wrong driver. This is the current info that I have for my adapter.

Vendor ID 1039, Device ID 0900

sis 900 pci fast ethernet adapter---About 80% sure.
[image: the info windows 7 gave me about the driver.]

Comment: If its fast ethernet, its pretty old, there's a chance the driver simply dosen't exist.

Comment: yea ive trieded hard. Should I just buy a pci card with the drivers?

Comment: ive also met a guy who has the same problem as me and has looked for over two years. Maby it is just time for a new network adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a driver for the  `SiS 900 Fast Ethernet Adapter` on the Windows Update catalog:

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=sis%20900

Access the page from a second PC (only works with the IE), download the driver, extract the CAB file and use the device manager to install the driver.

Comment: It Worked! Thank you I dont think I could have accomplished this without you.